# In Phoenix Live View, deleting an item removes DOM element put there by a phx-hook

Tags: phoenix-live-view

In a contrived [chat app](https://github.com/ijt/rantclub/tree/c383530ce9749beb21f2c60605576f0d047043f8), I added a smiley face to a div via a `phx-hook`.
After adding a chat, the smiley face is still there:

[image: After adding a chat]

However, after deleting the chat, the smiley disappears:

[image: After deleting the chat]

How can I prevent it from disappearing?

Answer (score 0):

It can be fixed by adding `phx-update="ignore"` to the div whose contents are generated by JavaScript:

```html
<div id="smiley" style="font-size: 80px" phx-hook="Smiley" phx-update="ignore"></div>
```